# How to prove universal Generalization

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have just learned something about universal Generalization in discrete math, and want to know how to prove it.
It is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63s68.png)

Comment: We will need to know how your proof system works in order to answer this.  For example, what is the convention as far as using this $c$ goes?  Because if $c$ is used as an individual *constant*, i.e. denoting a *specific* object, then clearly this is *not* a valid inference. So, $c$ must be used to represent some *arbitrary* object ... and the rules will need to be defined in order to reflect this usage.  But how, exactly? So, please add the relevant rules (in particular: Universal Generalization) to your post, because different systems can define Universal Generalization slightly differently.

Comment: It is a [rule of ineference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization). In some system of predicate logic with *Modus Ponens* as only rule of inference, it can be proved from suitable axioms.

Comment: yeah, you are right, c represents some arbitrary object